# VSCode: Auto Format on Save

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, save, extension-methods

I use last version of VSCode, I am on Windows10.
When I do the following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Test About section</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

The code is automatically auto formatted when I save:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}  {% block content %}
    <h1>Test About section</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to deactivate it, but I have been unable to. This is what I've tried:

- CTRL + Shift + P: 'Disable all Extensions' and also 'Disable all Extensions in Workspace'
- In the Settings, the "editor.formatOnSave" is set to false (I have checked in User Settings, Settings for the Workpspace, Settings for Workspace JSON, etc)
- Disabled Jinja and Prettier

Even tho I disabled my Extensions, when I hit [Save], the code is automatically formatted.
I am not sure where the settings get imported.

The project is new, I use Django, it's not linked to Git as well.
What I am doing wrong? I've been reading articles for the past hour but the issue keeps occurring, did I miss a setting or does a hidden setting get imported somewhere?

Comment: its because vscode hasn't a good django template prettier yet. but I made some configurations for my-self its not just bad. if you wish you could give it a try, and any improvement is highly appreciated.
[this is my config](https://gist.github.com/mh-firouzjaah/56bd7683936112c52131aae637815df3)

Comment: @MahdiFirouzjah The link you've provided is no longer availabled. 404

Comment: @RaahimFareed tnx for commet. it's now gist.github.com/mh-firouzjah